# Attribute autocorrect not allowed on element input at this point

Tags: w3c-validation

I have a problem validating my code.

`input type='text' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' autocapitalize='off' spellcheck='false' class='select2-input'`

w3c validator says the message: "Attribute autocorrect not allowed on element input at this point." I disabled the attribute autocapitalize but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

if you want to win with w3c validator, remove attributes that are not allowed on element and add them by javascript

Comment: Just as a reminder, adding invalid attributes via javascript *is still invalid* **plus** you'll have to write and maintain more, and the client will have to download and execute more code. Leaving the attribute there is better for everyone.